# Server not able to be accessed outside pi

Tags: pi-3, pixel

So I have a raspi 3 b with PIXEL. Ever since I installed it it has been giving me a headache. So I have a webserver, and when I go to the webpage on the pi, it works just fine. Now once I go to my laptop and try to go to the browser to go to the webpage and SSH in, neither work.

I am on the same LAN, so I'm not sure if it is necessary to do port forwarding. The stuff I've done with port forwarding I couldn't figure out either; I'm not sure whether or not I have to change stuff on the pi or not. So I've only assigned a port VIA the router.

Cheers! Ubuntu_User

Comment: This question is missing any meaningful data - it boils down to "it doesn't work" - if you want help you need to be more specific.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with: *"go to the IP address"*. What's going? Do you ping the raspi or do you use the IP address in the browser as http url? From where do you "go"? What means "*outside pi*"? Is it outside from your local area network on the internet? Please address me with @Ingo.

Comment: We need to know exactly how you are trying to access the server, e.g., instead of referring to "IP address", give the actual IP address you are using.  We also need to know if the laptop is on the same LAN as the pi or if you are trying to access it via the internet.  If you are not sure, give the laptop's IP address.  Edit these details into the question, do not leave them in comments, and ping "@goldilocks" when you are done.

Comment: I am done @goldilocks Thanks for helping.... I'm new so I have trouble knowing what is actually needed for information in my questions.

Answer (score 1):

> I am on the same LAN, so I'm not sure if it is necessary to do port forwarding.

If you only want to access it on the LAN you do not need to do that.

> The stuff I've done with port forwarding I couldn't figure out either; I'm not sure whether or not I have to change stuff on the pi or not.

Whatever you've done you should probably undo.

On a LAN, all devices have a private subnet address and they can communicate with each other using them. Unless they are using firewalls, this includes all ports.

> So I've only assigned a port VIA the router.

There's no point to that and you should undo it as well.

> Now once I go to my laptop and try to go to the browser to go to the webpage and SSH in, neither work.

Unfortunately you have not said how you tried to connect and exactly what happens; "doesn't work" is not informative because the browser must have given some error, e.g. "Connection timed out". As another example, if you are using a hostname (not an IP address) and your browser said it could not find the address or there is a name resolution problem it indicates that hostname is not being resolved by the local DNS services on your LAN.

You can look for devices with an SSH server running with:

```
nmap -sT -p22 192.168.0.0/24
```

Presuming that your LAN subnet is within `192.168.0.0/24`. Most of them will say "closed".

Comment: It gives me this

Comment: Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.2.15.

Comment: I hope this helps. Sorry I'm new to this sort of thing.